# CSS only collapsible list - list items overflow <ul>

Tags: html, css

I have this collapsible list created with css only, but somehow the list items overflow the `<ul>` element when it's opened. What do I need to do in order to fix this?

Html:

```css
.linkslist {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.linkslist .menu-trigger {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.linkslist input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}

.linkslist input[type="checkbox"]+label::after {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: initial;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-right: 5px;
  right: 10px;
  top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  content: '+';
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.linkslist input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label::after {
  content: '-';
}

.linkslist .menu-list {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.linkslist input[type="checkbox"]~ul.menu-list {
  height: 0;
  transform: scaleY(0);
}

.linkslist input[type="checkbox"]:checked~ul.menu-list {
  border: 1px solid #f90; /* For testing */
  margin-top: -1px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 180;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, .175);
  height: 100%;
  transform-origin: top;
  transition: transform .2s ease-out;
  transform: scaleY(1);
}

.linkslist .list-group-item {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 9px 7px;
  margin-left: 0 !important;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.linkslist .list-group-item a {
  color: inherit;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="linkslist">
  <input type="checkbox" id="list-item">
  <label for="list-item" class="menu-trigger">Select</label>
  <ul class="list-group menu-list">
    <li class="list-group-item"><a href="https://www.google.com" title="Google">Google</a></li>
    <li class="list-group-item"><a href="https://www.bbc.co.uk" title="Go to BBC">BBC</a></li>
    <li class="list-group-item"><a href="https://www.facebook.com" title="Go to Facebook">Facebook</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[See Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/bq5t1o9s/1/).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you expect to happen?

Comment: its because of `border` nothing else

Comment: Well, for testing I have added a border around the ul element. As you can see the content seems to overflow it. I'm planning to give it a box-shadow as well.

Comment: so you add this thats why its display. you remove it your problem solve

Comment: @BhargavChudasama, the border is for testing - in real life I would like to add box-shadow. It's in the css, but like with the border, the content overflows it.

Comment: Then you want to remove the `position:absolute` on the menu.

Comment: code working on its way its not working what you are thinking

Comment: @Paulie_D, yes, but I want the list items to open over any content below. If I remove `position: absolute`, it will push the content down...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Position absolute element take height as par parent relative element. Instead of `height:100%` set it to `height:auto` to fix this. 
Check updated snippet below..

```css
.linkslist {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.linkslist .menu-trigger {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.linkslist input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}

.linkslist input[type="checkbox"]+label::after {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: initial;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-right: 5px;
  right: 10px;
  top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  content: '+';
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.linkslist input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label::after {
  content: '-';
}

.linkslist .menu-list {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.linkslist input[type="checkbox"]~ul.menu-list {
  height: 0;
  transform: scaleY(0);
}

.linkslist input[type="checkbox"]:checked~ul.menu-list {
  border: 1px solid #f90; /* For testing */
  margin-top: -1px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 180;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, .175);
  height: auto;
  transform-origin: top;
  transition: transform .2s ease-out;
  transform: scaleY(1);
}

.linkslist .list-group-item {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 9px 7px;
  margin-left: 0 !important;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.linkslist .list-group-item a {
  color: inherit;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="linkslist">
  <input type="checkbox" id="list-item">
  <label for="list-item" class="menu-trigger">Select</label>
  <ul class="list-group menu-list">
    <li class="list-group-item"><a href="https://www.google.com" title="Google">Google</a></li>
    <li class="list-group-item"><a href="https://www.bbc.co.uk" title="Go to BBC">BBC</a></li>
    <li class="list-group-item"><a href="https://www.facebook.com" title="Go to Facebook">Facebook</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

remove `.linkslist .list-group-item{ margin-bottom:-1px`} and `height:inherit from .linkslist input[type="checkbox"]:checked~ul.menu-list`

```css
.linkslist {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.linkslist .menu-trigger {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.linkslist input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}

.linkslist input[type="checkbox"]+label::after {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: initial;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-right: 5px;
  right: 10px;
  top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  content: '+';
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.linkslist input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label::after {
  content: '-';
}

.linkslist .menu-list {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.linkslist input[type="checkbox"]~ul.menu-list {
  height: 0;
  transform: scaleY(0);
}

.linkslist input[type="checkbox"]:checked~ul.menu-list {
  border: 1px solid #f90;
  margin-top: -1px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 180;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, .175);
  box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, .175);
  height: inherit;
  transform-origin: top;
  transition: transform .2s ease-out;
  transform: scaleY(1);
}

.linkslist .list-group-item {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 9px 7px;
  margin-left: 0 !important;
  /* margin-bottom: -1px;*/
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.linkslist .list-group-item a {
  color: inherit;
  display: block;
}

body {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="linkslist">
  <input type="checkbox" id="list-item">
  <label for="list-item" class="menu-trigger">Select</label>
  <ul class="list-group menu-list">
    <li class="list-group-item"><a href="https://www.google.com" title="Google">Google</a></li>
    <li class="list-group-item"><a href="https://www.bbc.co.uk" title="Go to BBC">BBC</a></li>
    <li class="list-group-item"><a href="https://www.facebook.com" title="Go to Facebook">Facebook</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```